# Identify parameters of ARIMA model

Tags: matlab, time-series, identification, identify, arima

I am trying to build ARIMA model, I have 144 terms in my standardized time series, which represent residuals form original time series. This residuals, on which I would like to build ARIMA model, are obtained when I subtracted linear trend and periodical component from original time series, so residuals are stochastic component.

Because of that subtraction I modeled residuals like stationary series (d=0), so model is ARIMA(p,d,q)=ARIMA(?,0,?).

ACF and PACF functions of my residuals are not very clear as cases in literature for identification ARIMA models, and when I choose parameters p and q according to criteria that they are last values outside of confidence interval, I got values p=109, q=97. Matlab gave me error for this case:

> Error using arima/estimate (line 386)
>
> Input response series has an insufficient number of observations.

On the other side, when I am looking only to N/4 length of time series for identifying p and q parameters, I got p=36, q=34. Matlab gave me error for this case

> Warning: Nonlinear inequality constraints are active; standard errors may be inaccurate.
>
> In arima.estimate at 1113
>
> Error using arima/validateModel (line 1306)
>
> The non-seasonal autoregressive polynomial is unstable.
>
> Error in arima/setLagOp (line 391)
>      Mdl = validateModel(Mdl);
>
> Error in arima/estimate (line 1181)
>     Mdl = setLagOp(Mdl, 'AR' , LagOp([1 -coefficients(iAR)' ], 'Lags', [0 LagsAR ]));

How do I need to correct identify p and q parameters and what is wrong here? And wwhat does it mean in this partial autocorrelation diagram, why are last values so big?

[image: ACF of time series]
[image: PACF of time series]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [guide](https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/arimrule.htm) contains a lot of useful information about the correct estimation of ARIMA `p` and `q` parameters.

As long as I can remember from my studies, since `ACF` tails off after lag `q - p` and `PACF` tails off after lag `p - q`, the correct identification of `p` and `q` orders is not always straightforward and even the best practices provided by the above guide could not be enough to point you to the right direction.

Usually, a failproof approach is to apply an information criteria (like `AIC`, `BIC` or `FPE`) to several models with different orders of `p` and `q`. The model that presents the smallest value of the criterion is the best one. Let's say your maximum `q` and `p` desired order is `6` an that `k` is the number of observations, you could proceed as follows:

```
ll = zeros(6);
pq = zeros(6);

for p = 1:6
    for q = 1:6
        mod = arima(p,0,q);
        [fit,~,fit_ll] = estimate(mod,Y,'print',false);
        ll(p,q) = fit_ll;
        pq(p,q) = p + q;
     end
end

ll = reshape(ll,36,1);
pq = reshape(pq,36,1);

[~,bic] = aicbic(ll,pq+1,k);
bic = reshape(bic,6,6);
```

Once this is done, use the indices returned by the `min` function in order to find the optimal `q` and `p` orders.

On a side note, for what concerns your errors... well, the first one is pretty straightforward and is self-explanatory. The second one basically means that a correct model estimation is not possible.